# Angular way to set onerror on iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

Is there angular way to setup onerror attribute on iframe so I can use angular expressions. I've tried to use this:

```
<iframe onerror="{{vm.error()}}" ng-src="{{vm.url}}"/>
```

but got error:

> Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With default events you cant. But you can create a directive and assign to the `iframe`. Then in the logic of the directive , register to the `onerror` event and write your logic

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2, AfterViewInit } 
from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFrame]'
})
export class FrameDirective implements AfterViewInit {

 constructor(private iframeEl: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
 }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.iframeEl.nativeElement, 'error', () => {
        console.log('error caught in directive');
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure how this was marked as "answer". Can you elaborate just a little bit more? Sample code would help.

Comment: `this.renderer.listen(this.iframeEl.nativeElement, 'error', () => {
        console.log('error caught in directive');
    });` here there is no callback as `error`. It is same implementation as we do with `onload()` function in JS - but done with Directives in Angular - No HTTP response headers are present in `this.iframeEl.nativeElement` to check status.