# Display error when iframe refuse to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe, ecmascript-6

I've got this message when try to put the url in iframe:

> Refused to display '' in a frame because an ancestor violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

I have angular app that create iframe component with onerror binding as suggested in this answer [Angular way to set onerror on iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863090/387194), my angular 1.5 component `iframe` look like this:\

```
// iframe.controller.js
export default class iframeController {
    static $inject = ['$scope', '$element'];

    constructor($scope, $element) {
        // this display the iframe even that component have no template
        console.log($element.clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html());
        $element.on('error', () => {
            console.log('error');
            var call = () => {
                this.onerror();
            }
            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply(call);
            } else {
                call();
            }
        });
    }
}

// iframe.component.js
import controller from './iframe.controller';

export default {
    bindings: {
        onerror: '&'
    },
    controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
};
```

I've got error in console but the function is not executed. How to solve this, is there a way to get the error if iframe is refusing to display the page?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that there is no way to catch this error. The only way is to listen to the `load` event, and if it doesn't fire within some specified time (for example 5 seconds), assume that it failed to load.

Comment: @Gothdo unfortunately the load event is fired even when iframe is not loaded.

Comment: Then you can check if you can access the iframe content when the `load` event is fired.

Comment: @Gothdo I can't because it's different domain.

Comment: No to jesteś w dupie. You could check on the server side if the webpage has CSP or X-Frame-Options headers, but there's no guarantee that it will have the same headers when requested from a browser.

Comment: yes, I think there is no other option.